# Atiyah Macdonald – Exercise 2.15 (direct limit)

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, limits-colimits

Atiyah-Macdonald book constructs the direct limit of a directed system $(M_i,\mu_{ij})$, (where $i\in I$, a directed set, and $i\leq j$) of $A$-modules as the quotient $C/D$, where $C=\bigoplus_{i\in I} M_i$, and $D$ is the submodule generated by all the elements of the forms $x_i-\mu_{ij}(x_i)$, where $x_i\in M_i$ for some $i$ and $i\leq j$. Let $\mu \colon C \longrightarrow M$ be the projection map, and let $\mu_i$ be the restriction of $\mu$ to $M_i$ (which is identified with its image in the direct sum).

Now Exercise 2.15 asks us to prove the following – Show that if $\mu_i(x_i)=0$, then there exists $j\geq i$ such that $\mu_{ij}(x_i)=0$.

I have tried the following. $\mu_i(x_i)=0$ implies that $x_i\in D$. That is, $x_i$ is a finite sum of the elements of the form $a_l(x_l-\mu_{lk}(x_l))$, where $a_l\in A$, $x_l\in M_l$ and $k\geq l$. So, $x_i=\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{l_i}(x_{l_i}-\mu_{{l_i}{k_i}}(x_{l_i}))$. I don’t know how to proceed to find the index $j$ for which $\mu_{ij}(x_i)=0$. How do I proceed? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: There is a much easier construction for the *directed colimit* which shows the claim immediately. On the other hand, the construction indicated by Atiyah-Macdonald works for *arbitrary colimits*.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*People have pointed out that my hand-waving does not necessarily correspond to a proof. It was an absolute delight to revisit this proof. I have a new proof below, and it does not rely on the hand-wavy "minimality" hypothesis at all.*

Let $x_i\in M_i$, and suppose $x_i\in D$. As you have noted, $x_i$ is a finite $A$-linear combination of elements of $C$ of the form $x_a-\mu_{ab}(x_a)$. Absorbing the coefficients from $A$ in the terms $x_a-\mu_{ab}(x_a)$, we get terms of the same form. So, let $i_1,i_2,\dots,i_k,j_1,j_2,\dots,j_k\in I$, $x_{(1)}\in M_{i_1}\dots,x_{(k)}\in M_{i_k}$ and suppose $i_r\le j_r$ for $r=1,2,\dots,k$ as well as 
$$x_i = (x_{(1)}-\mu_{i_1j_1}(x_{(1)}))+\dots+(x_{(k)}-\mu_{i_kj_k}(x_{(k)})).\qquad(1)$$
Since $\{i,j_1,j_2,\dots,j_k\}$ is a finite subset of $I$, which is directed, there exists $j_{\ast}$ such that $i\le j_{\ast}$ and $j_r\le j_{\ast}$ for $r=1,2,\dots,k$. Also, for $r=1,2,\dots,k$, we have $i_r\le j_r$, so $i_r\le j_{\ast}$.

For $a\in I$, let $\pi_{a}:C\to M_{a}$ be the homomorphism given by restricting the canonical projection $\prod_{b\in I}M_b\to M_{a}$ to $C$. On the one hand, we have
$$\pi_a(x_i) = \begin{cases} x_i&\text{if $a=i$} \\
0 &\text{if $a\ne i$}\end{cases}$$
Based on (1), we also find that
$$\pi_a(x_i) = \sum_{i_b=a}x_{(b)} - \sum_{j_c=a}\mu_{i_cj_c}(x_{(c)}).$$
Then,
$$\mu_{aj_{\ast}}(\pi_a(x_i)) = \sum_{i_b=a}\mu_{i_bj_{\ast}}(x_{(b)})-\sum_{j_c=a}\mu_{j_cj_{\ast}}(\mu_{i_cj_c}(x_{(c)}))$$
Summing over $a$, we have
$$\sum_{a\in I}\mu_{aj_{\ast}}(\pi_a(x_i)) = \mu_{i_1j_{\ast}}(x_{(1)})-\mu_{j_1j_{\ast}}(\mu_{i_1j_1}(x_{(1)}))+\dots+\mu_{i_kj_{\ast}}(x_{(k)})-\mu_{j_kj_{\ast}}(\mu_{i_kj_k}(x_{(k)})).$$
The left side is $\mu_{ij_{\ast}}(\pi_i(x_i))$, and the right side is $0$. Therefore,
$$\mu_{ij_{\ast}}(x_i) = 0.$$

Comment: I just have one doubt, you say $y_l\neq 0$ if and only if $l =i$. Why is that? Some $y_l$ maybe equal to say $\mu_{{l-r},l}(y_{l-r})$ and they will cancel each other right?

Comment: @poorna That's a good observation, and it certainly is an oversight of mine. However, it just happens to work out right. You have a chain $y_{l-r}-\mu_{l-r,l}(y_{l-r})+y_l-\mu_{lm}(y_l)$. Replace $y_l$ with $\mu_{l-r,l}(y_{l-r})$ in *both* places, to get $y_{l-r}-\mu_{l-r,m}(y_{l-r})$. So, to circumvent the problem, we just have to assume $n$ is minimal.

Comment: Thank you! This is now very clear!

Comment: "After simplifying..." I think you are simplifying too much: $x_i = y_i + y_i' - \mu_{ij} (y_i) - \mu_{ik} (y_i')$, where $i \leq j, i \leq k$ (and more complicated examples) seem to be an option that can't be simplified any further. One has to work more to show that $\mu_{il} (x_i) = 0$, where $l \geq j, l \geq k$.

Comment: It would be nice if you could write out the minimality argument. What about the example $y_{ja} - \mu_{ja}(y_{ja})+y_{ji}-\mu_{ji}(y_{ji})$?  Here we make $y_{ja}+y_{ji}=0$, $\mu_{ja}(y_{ja})=0$

Comment: @CyrylLewkowicz Thank you for the example. I found the time to revisit my answer, and I have a proof that does away with the *ad hoc* minimality argument.

Comment: @KarlKroningfeld, we can only sum when $a\leq j_{*}$. I think it suffices to take the sum over the set $S=\{i, i_1,\ldots, i_k, j_1,j_2,\ldots j_k \}$ (removing any duplicacy).

Comment: A variation on this is to consider the endomorphisms $\widehat{\mu_{fg}} : C \to C$ defined by $s \mapsto s - \pi_f(s) + \mu_{fg}(\pi_f(s))$. In words, this operation removes the $f$-th component, maps it through $\mu_{fg}$ and adds it back to the $g$-th component, leaving everything else equal. Then the composite endomorphism $\bigcirc_{j \in J} \widehat{\mu_{jj^*}}$ where $J = \{i, i_1, j_1, \ldots, i_k, j_k\}$ (note that the order of composition doesn't matter) "translates" each component into the $j^*$-th component, so from $(1)$ we get the second-to-last equation in Karl's answer.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an alternative proof. The idea is to give another construction of the direct limit, a bit closer to the way it arises in algebraic geometry as germs of sections, and verify that construction satisfies the same universal property. This makes it clear where the hypothesis that the underlying poset is *directed* enters.

Let $N$ be the disjoint union of the underlying *sets* 
$$N=\coprod M_i,$$ and define an equivalence relation on $N$ by declaring $x \in M_i$ equivalent to $y \in M_j$ if there is some $k$ with $\mu_{jk}(y)=\mu_{ik}(x)$.

Let $M$ be the quotient of $N$ by this equivalence relation, write $\overline{x}$ for the equivalence class containing $x \in N$, and then define the structure of an $A$-module on $M$ by
$$a \overline{x}=\overline{ax} \quad \text{and} \quad \overline{x}+\overline{y}=\overline{x+y}$$ for $a \in A$ and $x,y \in M_i$ for some $i$ (here we use that the index set is *directed*, which implies that if $x \in M_i$ and $y \in M_j$ then there are $k \geq i,j$ and $z,w \in M_k$ with $\overline{x}=\overline{z}$ and $\overline{y}=\overline{w}$).

One (I won’t do it here, but it is routine) now verifies that $M$ together with the canonical maps $\nu_i:M_i \to M$ is a direct limit of $(M_i,\mu_{ij})$. The $0$ element of $M$ is the image of $0 \in M_i$ for some (any) $i \in I$. So by definition of the equivalence relation on $N$, the kernel of $\nu_i$ is precisely the set of $x \in M_i$ such that $\mu_{ij}(x)=0$ for some $j \geq i$.

By uniqueness of direct limits, the same is true with the other construction.

For the sake of completion, here is an example showing that the hypothesis that the set is directed is necessary for the result to remain valid. Consider the poset represented by the diagram $$3 \leftarrow 1 \rightarrow 2,$$ with $1 <2,3$ and no order relation between $2$ and $3$. Take all three groups $M_1=M_2=M_3=\mathbf{Z}$, with maps the identity $\mathrm{1}:M_1 \to M_2$ and the zero map $0:M_1 \to M_3$. In the direct limit, every element of $M_1$ goes to zero. Hence so does every element of $M_2$.

Comment: Nice! Definitely a conceptually different answer from mine: as intended, yours does make me think of germs of sections, while I wrote mine thinking of nodes in a network and not at all thinking of germs of sections. Though, one point at which they clearly do not differ is on why the hypothesis that $M_i$ and $\mu_{ij}$ encodes a functor from a directed set to the category of modules is *necessary*. Neither proof is satisfying in that regard.

Comment: @KarlKronenfeld Thanks! In my proof, the reason the poset being directed is necessary is in order to define the operations on $N$: thinking for a moment about how to define the sum of two elements $x \in M_i$ and $y \in M_j$, you realize you have to find $k \geq i,j$ and then add $\mu_{ik}(x)+\mu_{jk}(y)$. In other words, "restrict the sections to an open set on which they are both defined, and add them there."

Comment: ...and, thanks to you, I just realized that the way my answer is currently written somewhat obscures this point.

Comment: Yes, I got that the hypothesis (H) is necessary for $M$ is to be an $A$-module in your construction, which is where I was thinking most about germs of sections. It just does help to show there is not some proof that does not make use of H.

Comment: @KarlKronenfeld Ah, well, it's definitely not true without the hypothesis that the set be directed (thought the definition of direct limit still makes sense, the characterization of $\mathrm{Ker}(\mu_i)$ is not longer valid in general). So there is no proof without assuming $I$ is directed!

Comment: Yes, the mention of the hypothesis as a variable in your original answer seemed odd for the reason that we cannot even do the intended construction (though, as you seem to be saying, colimits and stuff can still be entertained since it is a diagram in a category).

Comment: @KarlKronenfeld The construction in my answer doesn't work, but the OP's construction of the direct limit does. In fact, it seems a little strange that Atiyah-Macdonald build the hypothesis into the definition of direct limit when it's not necessary.

Comment: Thanks, Stephen. It is indeed unclear why Atiyah-Macdonald prefer the more cumbersome construction of the filtered colimit.

Comment: It's always weird to get a random downvote on a rather technical answer years later, with no explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another proof. The result is immediate from the following claim:

**Claim:** Let $E \subseteq C$ be the subset consisting of all finite sums $\sum_{j \in J} x_j$ (where $x_j \in M_j$) that satisfy the following property: there exists a "threshold" $k \in I$ such that 1) $j \leq k$ for all $j \in J$ and 2) $\sum_{j \in J} \mu_{jl}(x_j) = 0$ for all $l \geq k$. Then $D = E$.

*Technical detail.* In the above statement, we allow terms $x_j$ to be equal to $0$. In particular, the subset $J \subseteq I$ is not uniquely determined by the element $\sum_{j \in J} x_j \in C$. However, the above property is evidently still well-defined (though the exact "threshold" $k$ may change).

We first verify that $E$ is a submodule of $C$. Let $\sum_{j \in J} x_j$ and $\sum_{j \in J'} y_j$ be elements of $E$ with respective "thresholds" $k, k' \in I$. By defining some $x_j$ and $y_j$ to be $0$, we may assume without loss of generality that $J = J'$ (increasing $k$ and $k'$ if necessary). Then for all $l \geq \max\{k, k'\}$, we have
$$
\sum_{j \in J} \mu_{jl}(x_j + y_j)
= \sum_{j \in J} \mu_{jl}(x_j) + \sum_{j \in J} \mu_{jl}(y_j) = 0,
$$
so $\sum_{j \in J} x_j + \sum_{j \in J'} y_j \in E$. Next, let $a \in A$. For all $l \geq k$, we have
$$
\sum_{j \in J} \mu_{jl}(ax_j) = a\sum_{j \in J} \mu_{jl}(x_j) = 0,
$$
so $a(\sum_{j \in J} x_j) \in E$. We have shown that $E$ is closed under addition and scalar multiplication, so $E$ is a submodule of $C$.

Now, observe that $E$ contains the generators of $D$, so $D \subseteq E$. Conversely, every sum $\sum_{j \in J} x_j \in E$ can be written $\sum_{j \in J} (x_j - \mu_{jk}(x_j)) \in D$, so $E \subseteq D$. This proves the claim.

Comment: @Anakhand You're correct, thanks!